# Consuming method auth Yodlee API

Tags: rest, yodlee

I am new to using this Yodlee tool, I created my developer account, and I am wanting to consume the sandbox APIs.
I am not being able to consume by rest with the Talend Api not even the initial method of "auth" (https://sandbox.api.yodlee.com/ysl/auth/token) to obtain the token; I'm passing the loginName, Api-version: 1.1, and content-type in the header as specified, then the clientId and the secret in the body.
The error message it returns is:

```
{
"errorCode": "Y303",
"errorMessage": "clientId or secret is missing",
"referenceCode": "rrt-8413800343306027303-c-gce-12663 ....."
}
```

Maybe the sandbox account doesn't allow me to do this, or am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the same issue. I am using RestSharp.

Finally found out that's a mismatched **Content-Type**.

It works after adding the header: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue with Google Apps Script, this is how I did it:

```
/************************************************************************************
 * 
 * This function starts the app, replace variables as necessary
 * 
 ************************************************************************************/

function primaryFunction() {

  // Declare variables
  var yodleeToken = {};
  var loginName = "ENTER_LOGIN_NAME";
  var clientID = "ENTER_CLIENT-ID";
  var clientSecret = "ENTER_CLIENT_SECRET";
  var yodleeURL = "https://sandbox.api.yodlee.com/ysl/";

  // Generate user token
  yodleeToken = getUserToken(loginName, clientID, clientSecret, yodleeURL);
}

/************************************************************************************
 * 
 * Creating function to get user token
 * 
 * @params loginName {String} Login name provided by Yodlee API
 * @params clientID {String} Client ID provided by Yodlee API
 * @params clientSecret {String} Client Secret provided by Yodlee API
 * @params yodleeURL {String} Yodlee API Endpoint
 *
 * References
 * https://av.developer.yodlee.com/
 *
 ************************************************************************************/

function getUserToken(loginName, clientID, clientSecret, yodleeURL) {

  // Specify headers
  var headers = {
    'Api-Version': '1.1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'loginName': encodeURIComponent(loginName)
  };

  // Build params
  var parameters = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': headers,
    'payload': encodeURI("clientId=" + clientID + "&secret=" + clientSecret),
    'redirect': 'follow',
    'timeout': 0,
    // 'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  };

  // Call API with params
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(yodleeURL + "auth/token", parameters);
  var responseJSON = JSON.parse(response);

  // return JSON response with Link Token
  return responseJSON;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass clientId and secret key in data-urlencode and remaining keys in header then it will return token

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://sandbox.api.yodlee.com/ysl/auth/token' \
--header 'Api-Version: 1.1' \
--header 'loginName: From your dashboard (Sandbox only)' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'clientId=Your clientId' \
--data-urlencode 'secret=Your secret'
```